# How to adjust a tab background image using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tab container into my pages. I am trying to change the background of each tab pane when I click those tab links. I can change the background for each tab pane but my background image is not adjust into tab pane. I can not view full image because it becomes larger, I want to fit full image into the background. plz help

Here is my markup & css:

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.hotel-info-bg 
{
  background: url('../img/content/slide_bg_hotel-info.jpg');
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs custom-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"><a href="#info" data-toggle="tab">info</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#amenities" data-toggle="tab">amenities</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#pets" data-toggle="tab">pets welcome</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#scene" data-toggle="tab">behind the scene</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in hotel-info-bg" id="info">
    <p>info</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="amenities">
    <p>amenities</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pets">
    <p>pets welcome</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scene">
    <p>behind the scene</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is s demo link: http://www.bootply.com/7OJqr7zXcn

Comment: can you give some fiddle link.. so that it will be easy to provide soluton?

Comment: @KiranVarthi see this: http://www.bootply.com/7OJqr7zXcn
here image size is 3375X2000px but it only shows half of image i want to display full image in my background without any repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope it will helps you -

```
 .hotel-info-bg{
       background:url("http://dummyimage.com/3375x2000/ebb0eb/f0f7fa.jpg") no-repeat center;
       background-size: 100%;
       height: 1200px;
       }
```